# How to intercept the dialog result of the payment in GooglePlay for Android

Tags: android, dialog

I'm doing an application with InAppBilling

I'm using the [TrivialDrive](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing)  example.

Here by pressing the button "BuyGas" dialog appears, for example

[image: dialog].

How do I intercept and substitute the answer ?

I cannot find where this code is located.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
    // ...
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
    startActivityForResult(intent,101);
```

and then

```
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    Log.i("MainActivity","onActivityResult called");
}
```